# CollectionType expected argument of type "string or null", "array" given at property path "cc"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4

Can someone explain why i am getting this error? I am using `CollectionType` for first time. Used [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html).
Here is my part of where i am trying to use `CollectionType`:

```
$builder->add('cc', CollectionType::class, [
         'required' => false,
         'entry_type' => EmailType::class
])
```

and here is my request:

```
{
    "email" => "test@test.com",
    "description" => "test description",
    "subject" => "test",
    "cc" => array:1 [
         0 => "test1@test.com"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you map this to a model, i.e. is the result from the form a PHP class? If so, could you post the code for that as well?

Comment: no, i am just trying to submit api request using formbuilder. actually i check if it works or not. bu without any success. is the request wrong? but when i update request to ```"cc" => "some string"``` validation returns that ```value is not valid``` @dbrumann

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So my problem was in `EmailEntity` where `cc` is string. I have used `Data Transformers` to fix this problem. Just added:

```
$builder->get('cc')
        ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
            function ($array) {
                return $array;
            },
            function ($array) {
                return json_encode($array);
            }
));
```

And don't forget to add `use Symfony\Component\Form\CallbackTransformer;`

Answer (score 1):

I had pretty much the same problem as you, but your exact solution didn't work for me, but you put me on a path to solve it, therefore gave you +1 of course. I wanted to write this as a comment but it was too long. Here is what I had to change your solution to to make it work:

```
$builder->get('myCollection')
    ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
        function ($array) {
            return $array;
        },
        function ($array) {
            $res = array();
            foreach($array as $item) {
                if ($item === null) {
                    $item = '';
                }
                $res[] = $item;
            }

            return $res;
        }
    ));
```